# Multiline string to dictionary

Tags: python, string

Let's say that I have the following multiline string. We can assume that title is always followed by a line.

```
"""
This is title
-------------------------
Author: Name of the author

Sentence 1.

Sentence 2.
"""
```

And I want to convert that to a dict like this:

```
{
    "title": "This is title",
    "author": "Name of the author",
    "body": "sentence 1.\n\nSentence 2.",
}
```

How can I split the first two lines with all those "-----" and later split the rest of the line by new line? Could you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: You asked how to split the lines. When you researched `python split strings`, did anything useful come up?

Comment: You could use a regular expression, or you could use `splitlines()` to get a list of lines to process.

Comment: The trick will be what happens to the second entry. How can you tell that `This is the second title` is a title, and not the third sentence of the first entry? Is there a delimiter (even if it's only 2 blank lines) between entries? Or do you detect a title only because it is followed by a line of hyphens?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the standard layout of all strings given. You can use multiple assignment and `str.split` to get your values split into variables then construct your `dict`. You just need to use `str.join` to re-join the strings after being split apart:

```
s = """
This is title
-------------------------
Author: Name of the author

Sentence 1.

Sentence 2.
"""

_, title, _, author, *body = s.split('\n')

data = {
    "title": title,
    "author": ' '.join(author.split()[1:]),
    "body": '\n'.join(body)
}
```

PrettyPrinted output:

```
{'title': 'This is title',
 'author': 'Name of the author',
 'body': '\nSentence 1.\n\nSentence 2.\n'}
```

Although this works it is a bit messy/adhoc for real world application. Please see if you can reformat how your data is supplied/stored if you want a more concrete solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this:

**What part could be considered consistent?**

IMO, the title, title line, and author are consistent. Regex allows us to describe a string format that we expect so, I wrote a regex format to describe the consistent parts.

**How do I get the rest?**

Regex also allows us to store the `start` and `end` positions of our matches. We can use these points to establish "the rest".

**Why not just add the body into the format?**

I couldn't figure it out in a simple way. There are too many conditions for double and single new lines that can also overlap the next entry (if there is one).

```py
import re

#describe the format of an entry
fmt  = re.compile(r'^(?P<title>([\w\d ]+))\n([-]+)\nAuthor: (?P<author>([\w\d ]+))\n\n', re.I|re.M)

# SINGLE ENTRY
dat  = ('Title 1\n'
        '-------------------------\n'
        'Author: Some Guy\n\n'
        'Sentence 1.\n\n'
        'Sentence 2.\n\n')

#get entry
m    = fmt.search(dat)

#make entry
book = dict(title=m.group('title'), author=m.group("author"), body=dat[m.end():len(dat)]) if m else None
 
#print book
print(book)

# MULTIPLE ENTRIES       
dat =  ('Title 1\n'
        '-------------------------\n'
        'Author: Some Guy\n\n'
        'Sentence 1.\n\n'
        'Sentence 2.\n\n'
        'Title 2\n'
        '-------------------------\n'
        'Author: Some Other Guy\n\n'
        'Sentence 1.\nSentence 2\n\n'
        'Sentence 3.\n\n')

#prime books
books = list()

#for storing data that needs to be carried over to the next iteration
le, lt, la = -1, "", ""

#make all but last entry
for m in fmt.finditer(dat):
    #this is always behind by 1 because we have to get `le` once before we can do this
    if le > -1: books.append(dict(title=lt, author=la, body=dat[le:m.start()]))
    #store this data to be carried over to the next iteration
    le, lt, la = m.end(), m.group('title'), m.group("author")
    
#make last entry   
books.append(dict(title=lt, author=la, body=dat[le:len(dat)]))
    
#print all books
print(books)
```